# adding each line in a text file into a list c#

Tags: c#

hi all i want to add the data in a text into 3 lists controls using c#

i have a main extra and side list and heres the contents of one of the text files

```
#main
9622164
90411554
57568840
53804307
44095762
89399912
88264978
26400609
45725480
53804307
53129443
51858306
53797637
91020571
27415516
57568840
89185742
20586572
99594764
19613556
53797637
75500286
51858306
89185742
26400609
90411554
44330098
91020571
90411554
47297616
75500286
28297833
26400609
27415516
45725480
53804307
89399912
89399912
29401950
9622164
#extra
79229522
41517789
80321197
76774528
44508094
83994433
45815891
26593852
74371660
80117527
80117527
10389142
10389142
90726340
51735257
!side
74530899
74530899
804000084
70095154
80344569
24508238
24508238
5318639
5318639
15800838
15800838
35027493
35027493
54974237
54974237
```

i want every line under #main in the main list every line under !side in the side list and every line under #extra in the extra list please help thanks

here is the code im using atm to add items to a list but i need to separate them

```
   String text = File.ReadAllText("test.ydk");

    var result = Regex.Split(text, "\r\n|\r|\n");

    foreach (string s in result)
    {
        MainDeck.Items.Add(s);
    }
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) and, specifically, what is not working with what you tried?

Comment: i have tried using streamreader to read the contents but cant get it to work and i have tried searching a solution but cant find anything that works

Comment: "but cant get it to work" ... what did not work? Any specific error message, weird output? We need code.

Comment: just wasnt reading the textfile at all idk why i can post what i had for code im a noob at this

Comment: this is the code im using atm it adds all the line to a list but i need to separate them into 3 lists         private void LoadDeck()
        {
            String text = File.ReadAllText("test.ydk");

            var result = Regex.Split(text, "\r\n|\r|\n");

            foreach (string s in result)
            {
                MainDeck.Items.Add(s);
            }
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you've already converted it to a string, you can use the string.split() function. This is using c#.

```
sting yourtextfile;
//make all the different sections the same
yourtextfile.replace("#main", "#");
yourtextfile.replace("#extra", "#");
yourtextfile.replace("!side", "#");
//make all the arrays
string[] all = yourtextfile.Split('#');
string[] main = all[0].Split('\n');
string[] extra = all[1].Split('\n');
string[] side = all[2].Split('\n');
```

Afterwards, convert the arrays to lists, and you have the three lists you wanted.

Comment: how exactly would i add this in thnx

Comment: didnt reliaze that with the ! what the list is its a deck of cards in a game and im trying to make a converter to convert a deck which is the text file above to a readable format on what cards are in that deck

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Linq` `Skip` and `Take` on the lines if you read your text file using `File.ReadAllLines`

Example:

```
// Read all the lines from the text file
var textLines = File.ReadAllLines("c:\\stackoverflow.txt");

// Skip first line `#main` and take all lines until `"#extra`
var mainItems = textLines.Skip(1).TakeWhile(x => !x.Equals("#extra"));

// Skip items before `#extra`, and take all before `!side`
var extraItems = textLines.SkipWhile(x => !x.Equals("#extra")).Skip(1).TakeWhile(x => !x.Equals("!side"));

// Skip items before `!side` and take the rest
var sideItems = textLines.SkipWhile(x => !x.Equals("!side")).Skip(1);
```

I would not reccomend this for large text files, but for your suppiled example it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to beat [File.ReadLined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) method that does just that - reads all lines from a file.

Than you can iterate and split in whatever way you need. `Foreach` with carrying last seen name over all items is reasonable approach.

Using `Aggregate` can give one statement solution if necessary. Sample for fancy version that uses immutable `Tuple` to pass values between steps and using `IEnumerable` to store items. Almost functionally clean code (except `TryParse` as there is no suitable version exists in the Framework):

```
int value;
var dictionaryOfNumberByName = File.ReadLines(@"c:\myFile.txt")
  .Aggregate(
     Tuple.Create("unknown", Enumerable.Repeat(Tuple.Create("", 0), 0)),
     (all, line) => int.TryParse(line, out value) ? 
          Tuple.Create(
            all.Item1,
            all.Item2.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(Tuple.Create(all.Item1, value),1))) : 
          Tuple.Create(line, all.Item2),
     all => all.Item2
       .GroupBy(
            item => item.Item1, 
            (key, source) => Tuple.Create(key, source.Select(v => v.Item2).ToList()))
       .ToDictionary(item => item.Item1, item => item.Item2));
```

Normal code should simply aggregate elements into mutable dictionary directly.

```
var dictionaryOfNumberByName = File.ReadLines(@"c:\myFile.txt")
  .Aggregate(Tuple.Create("unknown", new Dictionary<string, List<int>>()),
   (all, line) => { 
      int value;
      if(!int.TryParse(line, out value))
      {
          all.Item2.Add(line, new List<int>());
          return Tuple.Create(line, all.Item2); // switch current word
      }
      else
      {
        all.Item2[all.Item1].Add(value);
        return all;
      }
});
```

Comment: +1, I alwys forget about `Aggregate`, much better than my silly Skip/Take answer

Comment: @sa_ddam213 - Aggregate is one line, but can be considered insane and not really effective if not using mutable types... You solution looks easy to understand (not very optimal, but easy to prove working)...

Answer (score 0):

Use `File.ReadAllLines` to get the content of each line in a string array, then iterate over each item in the list, setting a flag that controls which list you (re)add each item to.  It's not the most efficient, as you have to process each line twice, but it is very clean and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

With this you can have a single collection with all values separated:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> results = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
string line;
int count = -1;
using (var reader = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\Jose\Desktop\bla.txt"))
{
      while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
           if (!Regex.IsMatch(line, @"\d"))
           {
               results.Add(line, new List<string>());
               count++;
           }
           else
           {
                results.ElementAt(count).Value.Add(line);
           }
       }

}
```